# fscanf into a 2, 2dArrays from a text file

Tags: c, file, multidimensional-array, scanf

Im being asked to:

**Write a program that takes as input two 3x3 arrays in file "Matrices.txt", whose contents are:
3 7 1 3 4 3 6 5 0
4 1 5 2 0 4 6 1 2**

I am unsure how I am to go about using fscanf to pull the numbers from the txt file and put them into two seperate 2d arrays.

This is what I got going on:

`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
 
  int matrixA [3][3];
  int matrixB [3][3];
  FILE *fptr;
  int i,j = 0;
  
   fptr = fopen("Matrices.txt","r");
    if(fptr == NULL){
      printf("Errpr! File was not created!");
      exit(1);
      }
  
      while(!feof(fptr)){
        fscanf(fptr,"%d%d", &matrixA[i][j]);
        i++;
        j++;
      }//while loop
    

    fclose(fptr);
    return 0;
}
```

`

Comment: `int i,j = 0;` is equivalent to `int i; int j = 0;` I.e. it leaves `i` *uninitialized*

Comment: Also please read [Why is “while( !feof(file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feoffile-always-wrong)

Comment: Besides those two issues, your code is pretty fine.

Comment: Opening a file for reading should never create a file, so `printf("Errpr! File was not created!");` seems like a strange error message.  If `fopen` fails, tell the user why with `perror`:  eg `if(fptr == NULL){ perror("Matrices.txt"); exit(1); }`. (But don't hard code the name.)

Comment: It's not at all clear to me exactly how you want to distribute the inputs into the arrays, but perhaps you are looking for `while( i < 3 && j < 3 && 2 == fscanf(fptr, "%d%d", &matrixA[i][j], &matrixB[i][j])){`. Also, make sure you initialize `i`.  The line `int i,j = 0;` initializes only `j`.